# Should I be adding aliases to /etc/profile instead of /etc/basrhc?

Tags: bash, bashrc

I've been adding them to /etc/basrhc, and that works most of the time.

But I noticed that when I `su` to another user, I lose all my aliases.

It turns out that `/etc/bashrc` is only loaded when the terminal is opened, not on login. And it seems that `/etc/profile` is loaded on login. So, is that where I should really have put all those aliases?

Comment: You should be using shell functions, not aliases.  Aliases are less featureful, more brittle, and offer no advantages over shell functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put them in `/etc/profile.d/buttles_aliases.sh`

The `/etc/profile` file probably contains this code:

```
if [ -d /etc/profile.d ]; then
  for i in /etc/profile.d/*.sh; do
    if [ -r $i ]; then
      . $i
    fi
  done
  unset i
fi
```

Unfortunate lack of quotes, so don't put a space in your filename.

Comment: And that file will load those aliases for all users? My aliases are general purpose time-saving things that I want everyone to have.

Comment: Yes, see the bash manual, https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Startup-Files